# Notify AWS all ECS instances when file in S3 changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

Wanted to know is there a way to notify all ECS instances in case a file is uploaded or newer version is uploaded to S3?

As far as I know, SNS, SQS or activity will only notify the first instance that will recieve the notification/message.

Comment: SNS will deliver a notification to all parties subscribed to the relevant topic.

Comment: What are the ECS instances? Are they web-servers or background processes? The answer decides how you deliver the events.

Comment: All of them are webaervers. @Parsifal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNS is the standard way to broadcast notifications; [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) describes how to configure it with S3.

If all listeners are webserver, then the easiest way to connect them is with an [HTTP Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html) from SNS.

You'll need to make the following changes to your application:

- On startup, make sure that your *server's* endpoint is subscribed to the SNS topic. You *can't* simply subscribe a load-balancer endpoint, because it will distribute the traffic; not everything will receive it.
- Your application must listen for the [subscription confirmation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-subscription-confirmation-json) request and confirm the subscription.
- Your application then listens for the [notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-notification-json) request, and does whatever it needs to do.

Alternatively, you can subscribe SQS queues -- one per interested server -- but that would become a management chore if you have an auto-scaled fleet.